# Return value based on duplicate columns

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, duplicates

```
Table:    
firstname  |   lastname   |  age      
Joey       |   Sanchez    |  33   
Joey       |   Sanchez    |  33   
Rachel     |   Dudok      |  28
```

I'm trying to make a MySQL select statement that returns a value "**ERROR**" in the age column when 2 columns are duplicates

I tried the Case statement but it only ends up returning 1 row.

```
 SELECT 
 Firstname,
 Lastname,
 CASE
    WHEN count(firstname) AND count(lastname) AND count(age) >= 2 
     THEN '**ERROR**'
     ELSE age
 END
 FROM Table;
```

Comment: Clean your data. Consider that you can have 2 20 year old john doe's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `group by`:

```
 select Firstname
      , Lastname
      , case when count(*) > 1 then '**ERROR**' else age end
 from Table
 group by  Firstname
         , Lastname
         , age;
```

Or in case you want to return all rows with duplicates:

```
 select t.Firstname
      , t.Lastname
      , case when (select count(*)
                   from Table
                   where Firstname = t.Firstname and
                         Lastname = t.Lastname and
                         age = t.age) > 1 then '**ERROR**' else age
         end
 from Table t
```

Comment: this ends up removing 1 row, is there a way to return all 3 rows but just have the age column show the "ERROR" value?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to deal with duplicate records.  Probably the best way for most situations is to prevent them entirely using UNIQUE keys:

```
    ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`firstname`,`lastname`,`age`);
```

However, as you already have duplicates and need to locate them, that is for later.  For your particular request, here is one way to handle it:

```
    SELECT s.`firstname`,s.`lastname`,IF(c.rc > 1,'ERROR',s.`age`) AS 'age'
      FROM `myTable` AS s
      JOIN (SELECT `firstname`, `lastname`, `age`, count(*) AS rc
              FROM `myTable`
             GROUP BY `firstname`,`lastname`,`age`)
        AS c  ON c.`firstname` = s.`firstname`
             AND c.`lastname` = s.`lastname`
             AND c.`age` = s.`age`;
```

If you only want to receive 1 row per name/age combination, add DISTINCT to the outer query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT s.`firstname`,s.`lastname`,IF(c.rc > 1,'ERROR',s.`age`) AS 'age'
      FROM `myTable` AS s
      JOIN (SELECT `firstname`, `lastname`, `age`, count(*) AS rc
              FROM `myTable`
             GROUP BY `firstname`,`lastname`,`age`)
        AS c  ON c.`firstname` = s.`firstname`
             AND c.`lastname` = s.`lastname`
             AND c.`age` = s.`age`;
```